# Display posts from given category

Tags: wordpress

I want to display posts from the given category. But I would like to give this category in page editor.

```
    $wpbp = new WP_Query(array("category_name" => 'music', "posts_per_page" => 50));
```

Above snippet gives me all the posts from music. But instead of giving category slug, I would like to use a variable.Please see below

```
    $wpbp = new WP_Query(array("category_name" => '$category', "posts_per_page" => 50));
```

Right now the shortcode that I give is `[display-posts]` but I would like it to be like this `[display-posts category='music']`

How to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Show the code of shortcode `[display-posts]`

Comment: Extract params from short code and use them.

Comment: Code is of one big page. Main part which display posts is here if ($wpbp->have_posts()) : while ($wpbp->have_posts()) : $wpbp->the_post();
   ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See full working code below:

```
function display_posts($params, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'type' => 'style1'
    ), $params));


    ob_start();

    $wpbp = new WP_Query(array("category_name" => $params['category'], "posts_per_page" => 50));
    // remaining code



 return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('display-posts','display_posts');
```

Use `[display-posts category='music']` to get post from music category.

Comment: This is exactly what am looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
$wpbp = new WP_Query(array("category_name" => $category, "posts_per_page" => 50));
```

I think it's right your problem in variable $category can not be placed between the 'quote'.

Answer (score 0):

List Category Posts allows you to list posts from a category into a post/page using the [catlist] shortcode. When you're editing a page or post, directly insert the shortcode in your text and the posts will be listed there. The basic usage would be something like this:

```
[catlist id=1]

[catlist name="news"]
```

**with limit**

```
[catlist id=1 numberposts=10]
```

[List category posts extension for your requirement](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/)

Comment: Thanks. But don't want to use plugin.

Comment: you can not use plugin but it's code see and understand how to work and implement.